# create a function that returns the name of the day of the week using the passed parameter N ( N is a vector with a set of values of arbitrary length)

Tags: r, function

How do I create a function that returns the name of the day of the week in English using the passed parameter N, and pass a vector with a set of values of arbitrary length as the parameter N?
Below is my code, but it doesn't work

```
days_of_the_weeks <- function(N) {
    english <- c('Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday', 'Thursday','Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday')
    l <- c(:)
    for(english in l) {
    z <- english[c(x=l)]
    }
    return(z)
    }
    print(days_of_the_weeks(c(3,5,7,8,2)))
```

Comment: N-in my function there should be a vector of values that will correspond to the days of the week, i.e. in the output I want to get a set of values. For example, if I enter the value N< - c(3,5,6,7), then get (3-Wednesday, 5-Friday, e.t.c.).

Comment: what about numbers more than 7? should it throw and error?

Comment: No, it should also work with them

Comment: So 8 will correspond to 1, 9 to 2 and so on?

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right, there will be an operation the remainder of the division by N (N%%7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this code provides the solution you are looking for,

```
days_of_weeks <- function(N) {
  N <- N[!is.na(N)]
  stopifnot(N >= 0)
  
  for(i in seq_along(N)) {
    if(N[[i]] > 7) {
      N[[i]] <- N[[i]] %% 7
    }
  }
  english <- c("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday","Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday")
  english[N]
}

days_of_weeks(c(3, 5, 7, 2, 8, 9, 10))

[1] "Wednesday" "Friday"    "Sunday"    "Tuesday"   "Monday"    "Tuesday"   "Wednesday"

days_of_weeks(c(3,5,7,2, 8, NA, 10))

[1] "Wednesday" "Friday"    "Sunday"    "Tuesday"   "Monday"    "Wednesday"
```

Here you only need a for loop to ensure that values of `N` that our more than 7 and for choosing the corresponding weekdays there is no need for `for` loops. I also provide 2 extra conditions for values below 1 and also `NA` values.